# Suitescript: Map Reduce vs Mass Update

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Let's say I've to load and save all Sales Orders (or any record) to trigger a User Event Script or just set a field...

Which one of those would run faster, or which one would be the best practice to do that development?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that only one time and your record follows a saved search, go for a mass update.
If you need to schedule it according to some criteria, go for a map/reduce